# Solving system of linear equations in specific order

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, algorithm

I know how to solve set of linear equations using `Solve`, or by hand of course. However, my current problem requires me to solve the equations **in a specific order**, in order to extract a list `spacing` of particular coefficients.

Consider two equations of `a1, a2` with integral coefficients,

```
{- 2a1 - a2 == b1, a1 - a2 == b2}
```

There are two ways to solve this.

- Use `-2a1 - a2 = b1` to solve for `a1`, and collect `spacing[1] = -2` as the coefficient of `a1`; then put the solution for `a1` into the second equation, getting `- 3/2 a2 - b1/2 = 2b2`, and collect `spacing[2] = -3/2` as the coefficient of `a2`.
- Use `a1 - a2 = b2` instead to solve for `a1`, collecting `spacing[1] = 1`, and later `spacing[2] = -3` from coefficient of `a2`.

For my problem, the second way of solving is the "right way", yielding integral `spacing`. (Before extracting the coefficients to `spacing`, I'm **not** allowed to "multiply on both sides".)

My goal is to implement an automated solution for more general system of linear equations of `a1, a2, a3, ...`, with an **integral** coefficient matrix, such that the `spacing` extracted from the solution process is **integral**.

Essentially, I just need to figure out the **order** (which equation to solve for `a1`, for `a2`, etc.) of solving the equations. But how to achieve this? (at the moment I'm trying to randomize the ordering until I get what I want)

Comment: So may you use the Euclidean algorithm on each column as you go? And you want "an" order that works, not "the" order? (I don't think the order is unique.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right, "an" order is enough. Thanks, I'll look up this algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelE2 By Euclidean algorithm do you mean the one to compute gcd?

Comment: It can be used to compute the GCD, yes. But it can be used here to subtract rows, while reducing the leading entry. Pick row  $r_i$ with smallest nonzero entry in the column that is being reduced; let the entry be $a$. Then replace another row $r_j$ with entry $b = qa + r$, $0\le r < a$, by $r_j - q \cdot r_i$ and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what `spacing[j]` represents, but the diagonal matrix in `SmithDecomposition[amat]` might yield the spacings, if that is all you want to find. If you need the algorithm, `SmithDecomposition[]` does not yield the **order**, may look at the algorithm (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133076/computing-the-smith-normal-form or google it).

Comment: I am also a little uncertain on the true meaning of `spacing`, but you can notice that if we define the design matrix of the system `mat = {{-2, -1}, {1, -1}}` , the two `spacing`'s that you mentioned can be generated by `{mat[[1, 1]], -mat[[1, 2]]/mat[[1, 1]]*mat[[2, 1]] + mat[[2, 2]]}` and `{mat[[2, 1]], -mat[[2, 2]]/mat[[2, 1]]*mat[[1, 1]] + mat[[1, 2]]}` so maybe there's a more general way to write this for other design matrices

Comment: I don't want to flood the comments, and I'm not sure if this even is helpful, but is
`mat = {{-2, -1}, {1, -1}};`
`aVec=Array[a,2];`
`GroebnerBasis[mat . aVec, aVec, CoefficientDomain -> Integers]`
`(* {3 a[2], a[1] - a[2]} *)`
useful at all?

Comment: I think HermiteDecomposition might be the function of interest. The GroebnerBasis in another comment should also be fine but is overkill for a linear system (and for a large system it will be slower).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! HermiteDecomposition does seem to do the job efficiently.

Comment: @ydd The GroebnerBasis does sometimes yield the numbers correctly, though they don't appear in nice order. `HermiteDecomposition` seems to be the best option.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `SmithDecomposition[]` also does the job, it seems. In the examples I tested the diagonal elements appear in expected order. The results from `SmithDecomposition[]` and `HermiteDecomposition` don't always agree, but both seem to yield valid `spacing` in good order.

Comment: I agree `HermiteDecomposition[]` is probably best, though I don't know the application here. The Smith normal form has the property that a diagonal entry of the diagonal matrix divides the succeeding diagonal entry. It's an old friend I used to use, and I'm always forgetting the Hermite normal form. The divisibility requirement means `SmithDecomposition[mat]` and `HermiteDecomposition[mat]` do not have to have the same diagonal, even up to permutation. For instance, `mat = {{6, -6, 6}, {8, 4, -6}, {-14, 10, -9}}`.